# error in flutter , after flutter update-packages --force-upgrade

Tags: flutter

after update flutter packages i got this errors

`Failed to build iOS app`
`Error (Xcode): ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/leak_tracker_testing-2.0.3/lib/src/leak_testing.dart:146:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'notGCed'.`

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue you have described here after updating Flutter to version `3.19.4`. I also ran the command `flutter update-packages --force-upgrade` and updated the `intl` package to `0.19.0`.

To resolve the problem in my situation, I downgraded Flutter to version `3.19.0` and the `intl` package to `0.18.1`. Here are the steps I followed:

1. Downgrade Flutter to version `3.19.0` by running:

   ```
   flutter downgrade 3.19.0
   ```
2. Downgrade the `intl` package to `0.18.1` by specifying the version in your `pubspec.yaml` file:

   ```yaml
   dependencies:
     intl: ^0.18.1
   ```
3. Run `flutter pub get` to fetch the downgraded packages.

This solved the issue for me. It appears that there might be compatibility issues with the latest updates. If anyone has faced a similar problem and found a different solution, I'd be keen to learn more.